# Compare two (nested) lists/tuples of NumPy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples

Let us say I have two nested structures of the following kind:

```
[(array, (array, array, array)), (array, (array, array, array))]
```

All of the interesting data inside are NumPy arrays. What is the easiest way to compare two of such data structures? I could index and compare each of the corresponding arrays individually, but that is a lot of indexing and typing.

If there is an easy way to just "swallow" all of the numbers in the contained arrays and "serialise" them unambiguously into one NumPy array, that resulting array would be easy to compare. I am mainly interesting in checking if two such arrays are equal (`==` or `np.allclose()`). I have naïvely tried doing so by throwing a `np.array` around the whole thing but that only converts the outermost list to a NumPy array.

Comment: It is always a list of tuple of size 2 with first element an `array` and second element a tuple of arrays?

Comment: @Holt Yes, always that tuple structure but in fact, the list may contain more of them.

Comment: @mgilson I may want to accept tiny numerical differences - hence `allclose`.

Comment: @mgilson actually a == b gives me "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Answer (score 1):

To work with `np.allclose`, you'll need your own comparison function.

```
def compare(a, b):
    if isinstance(a, (list, tuple)) and isinstance(b, type(a)):
        for aa, bb in zip(a, b):
            if not compare(aa, bb):
                return False  # Short circuit
        return True
    else:  # numpy arrays
        return numpy.allclose(a, b)
```

Of course, you could get more fancy (passing `kwargs` down from `compare` to `allclose` for example) and your input checking could be more robust, but this should give you the general idea ...

Comment: If the 2 lists have the same numeric values, but different array objects, that `==` produces a `truth value` error.  `==` tests between arrays can produce a a boolean array.  The `allclose` approach should be safer.

Comment: @hpaulj -- derp.  Thanks.  (you can tell I haven't been working with `numpy` a lot lately).  I'll remove the first bit then.

Comment: Clever. I notice that `and isinstance(b, type(a))` also ensures that one is actually checking two objects of the same type and since this works to some extent as input validation, it's a bit unfortunate that this also triggers the `numpy.allclose` comparison when that fails. I am adding a variation of your answer hoping to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slight modification of https://stackoverflow.com/a/31662874/865169 to try to filter out the situation where a and b are not of the same type, i.e. are not comparable in the sense we are trying to check here:

```
def compare(a, b):
    if not isinstance(b, type(a)):
        raise TypeError('The two input objects must be of same type')
    else:
        if isinstance(a, (list, tuple)):
            for aa, bb in zip(a, b):
                if not compare(aa, bb):
                    return False  # Short circuit
            return True
        else:  # numpy arrays
            return np.allclose(a, b)
```